# Count and sum multiple columns from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have the bellow tables:

Table users

```
| id | profile_img |
--------------------
|   21|     name.img|
|   22|     name.img|
|   33|     name.img|
```

Table user_translations

```
|id | user_id |first_name |
--------------------------
|  1|    21   |  panais |
|  2|    22   |  andreas|
|  3|    33   |  minas  |
```

Table about

```
| id | user_id |
----------------
|   1|    33   |
|   2|    22   |
|   3|    21   |
```

Table things

```
| id | user_id |
----------------
|   1|    33   |
|   2|    22   |
|   3|    21   |
|   4|    21   |
|   5|    33   |
```

Each user can write

> about articles to `about table` and thing articles to `things table`

I want to get all users with the total numbers of articles. In other words I want to get that minas from above `user_translations` table has wrote total 3 articles.

Any help is appreciated.

### Updated

I've posted an answer

Comment: Try using `count(DISTINCT (things.id))` and `count(DISTINCT(about.id))`...See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without laravel @George Pant has a good answer.

Laravel query builder to answer the question:

```
DB::table('users')
            ->join('about', 'users.id', '=', 'about.user_id')
            ->join('things', 'users.id', '=', 'things.user_id')
            ->join('user_translations', 'users.id', '=', 'user_translations.user_id')
            ->where('user_translations.locale', '=', 'en')
            ->select('first_name', 'last_name', 'user_translations.user_id',
                DB::raw('count(DISTINCT(things.id)) + count(DISTINCT(about.id)) as articles')
            )
            ->groupBy('first_name', 'users.id')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help you with laravel's query builder but in pure mysql the query you need is something like:

```
SELECT ut.`firstname`,ut.`lastname`,COUNT( DISTINCT(a.`id`) ) + COUNT( DISTINCT(t.`id`) ) as total_articles
FROM `user_translations` ut
INNER JOIN `about` a ON a.`user_id`=ut.`user_id`
INNER JOIN `things` t ON t.`user_id`=a.`user_id`
GROUP BY ut.`user_id`
```

So perhaps you could use `DB::raw` and get what you want

Comment: Thank you very much you help me to get the answer

Comment: Happy my answer helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question but this query lists all the users in the users table and then lists the number of entries they have in the about and things tables:

```
SELECT users.ID, user_translations.first_name, COUNT(DISTINCT about.ID) AS abt, COUNT(DISTINCT things.ID) as thg
FROM users LEFT JOIN user_translations ON users.ID = user_translations.UserID
LEFT JOIN about ON users.ID = about.userID
LEFT JOIN things ON users.ID = things.userID
GROUP BY users.ID, user_translations.first_name
```